# Random() in sqlite and Android sdk

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to extract random rows from the app sqlite database in Android. I'm aware that, with sqlite, you can select random rows with:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

In the app, I have something like this

```
return mDb.query(TABLE, new String[] {"col1", "col2"}, null, null, null, null, "Random()", "2");
```

this is for extract two random rows in table TABLE. But it keeps returning the same rows. What's wrong wit the statement?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't looked into this specific Random() but I know some Random()'s are time based and if it executes at the during the clock cycle wouldn't the Random() return the same thing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try this

```
Cursor cursor = this.db.query("YourTable Order BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",
                new String[] { "*" }, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: i don't understand why this works (also, recent versions of android are enforcing escaping more, so this may stop working)

Answer (score 4):

Set query like below:

```
public Cursor getRandomDataItemFromDb(String tableName, int limit) {
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName+ " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT " + limit, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return cursor;
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

**Done**

Comment: this comment is definitely a while later but your answer helped me immensely!

Answer (score 3):

Use the orderBy clause like this

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, "RANDOM() limit 1");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the random function as in a string in your query. I gave you a sample below.

```
String orderBy = "RANDOM()";
Cursor dbc = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, columnArray, null, null, null, null, orderBy, null);
```